# Is it possible to apply Blend behavior using style or template?

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I'm very happy with my small collection of Blend behaviors, actions and triggers - they are easy to use and powerful. But I still can't figure out how to avoid applying them on per element basis. For example, if I have a behavior as such:

```
<Rectangle>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <il:MouseDragElementBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Rectangle>
```

and I have a few draggable rectangles in my Window, each of them has to have the above markup to be draggable. What I would like to do is to be able to write something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="RectangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
    <Setter Property="i:Interaction.Behaviors" 
        Value="il:MouseDragElementBehavior"/>
</Style>
```

It could be style, template, or some other way to avoid behavior or action markup repetition. The best solution I came up so far is creating a special behavior for the container (when attached, it enumerates children attaching to the children events).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and I [posted on my blog](http://www.livingagile.com/Blog/July-2010/Attaching-Behaviors-from-the-Expression-Blend-SDK-) on how to create an attached property to work around this shortcoming of the Blend SDK.

Comment: this is a broken link. see [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but what I would probably do is create an attached property that can hold a collection of Behaviors. In the property changed handler of that property, I would enumerate the collection and add each of the behaviours to the real Interation.Behaviors property. It's a bit messy, but it ought to work.

### Update

This approach won't work without a good deal more work: the problem is that Behaviors and Triggers can only be attached to one object at a time. This is probably why the limitation on applying them using a style exists in the first place. To get this to work you would need to create some kind of Trigger or Behavior factory.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own class that inherits from `Rectangle` and apply the behavior there.

Comment: In that case I would not even need behavior - I could wire up events directly.
Naw, I'd rather leave our designer something to do...