# EventToCommand in button style

Tags: wpf, triggers, mvvm-light

I want to assign the same command to all my buttons on my user control.  I use MVVM Light and I have tried all combinations.  I have also tried to use EventSetter, but this does not allow binding to a command in the ViewModel

Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:
`<Style x:Key="CalculatorButton" TargetType="telerik:RadButton">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ButtonClick}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>`

Design Time error: A value of type 'EventTrigger' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerCollection'.

Runtime Error: The value \"System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger\" is not of type \"System.Windows.TriggerBase\" and cannot be used in this generic collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, an `i:EventTrigger` is not the same thing as an `EventTrigger`.  The former is part of the `System.Windows.Interactivity` and the latter is a core part of WPF.  Since `EventToCommand` uses `System.Windows.Interactivity`, you'll have to use a different mechanism than `Style.Triggers` to use it in a style.  You can use my technique described in this StackOverflow answer:

- [How to add a Blend Behavior in a Style Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter/4779168#4779168)