# SelectedItem set after Right Click event on DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I have a `DataGrid` as below

```
<DataGrid Margin="10,89,10,10" 
          AlternatingRowBackground="#FFB9E2FF" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ResultDetails, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          IsReadOnly="True" 
          SelectionMode="Single">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonUp">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ResultGridMouseClickCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ResultGridDblClickCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

And I have a `RelayCommand` to handle `MouseRightButtonUp` event

```
private void ExecResultGridMouseClickCommand()
{
    if (SelectedItem == null) return;

    DisplayInfo(SelectedItem);
}
```

Let's say I have 5 items in `DataGrid`:
    Item1
    Item2
    Item3
    Item4
    Item5

When `DataGrid` init, `SelectedItem` is null.
Then user right click on `Item3`, `RelayCommand` fire, but `SelectedItem` still is null. 
User right click on `Item1`, `RelayCommand` fire again, however, `SelectedItem` return `Item3`, and my code was display wrong item's details.

Is it possible to retrieve which item are selected in `MouseRightButtonUp` event? Or I should use other event instead?

Comment: Why don't you apply you logic after SelectedItem Change instead of using trigger.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I want to display information when user right click only. Setter of `SelectedItem` will be triggered by double click and click. For this case, I may need a flag in right click event, and display info in setter of `SelectedItem` when flag on, then reset the flag, but I think this not a good approach, or this is a best practice?

Comment: Another option I found is use `VisualTreeHelper` in `MouseButtonEventArgs` to locate the selected row, I haven't try this yet, because I want to find some solution without UI element.
for other people reference: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html

Comment: Updated: for my first comment about `SelectedItem`, I found 1 more problem, which after display the information, user are able to right click the item to display the info again, however, `SelectionChanged` event or `SelectedItem` will not be triggered when select the same item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the best approach is to apply a style to the `DataGridRow`, that way you ensure that the command is being applied to the item the user is actually clicking and you forget about the SelectedItem. Note the following:

- DataContext will now the item itself instead of the collection.
- You cannot use `<i:Interaction.Triggers>` inside a `Style`. There seem to be [workarounds to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321966/interaction-triggers-in-style-in-resourcedictionary-wpf). Or you can try switching to the mighty Attached Command Behaviors: you have an example of usage inside a style [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035023/firing-a-double-click-event-from-a-wpf-listview-item-using-mvvm), second answer.

Comment: @Naxto Thanks for the ans. At the end, I have change the `DataGrid` with hover-select enable (inspired by your ans), it will assign `SelectedItem` before right click, drawback is, it will assign even control is disable...