# event to command in style

Tags: c#, wpf

For below syntax:

```
<Button Content="click" >
    <Interact:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Interact:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
            <Interact:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" />
        </Interact:EventTrigger>
    </Interact:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

How can I create a `Style` for `Button`? I want to apply this command to a lot of buttons. I'm using `System.Windows.Interactivity` `dll` for event to command.

Comment: There's no direct solution. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321966/interaction-triggers-in-style-in-resourcedictionary-wpf for possible options.

Comment: @Dennis So I should use an extra class for that? is that your conclusion too?