# Post selection mouse click event on ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

### background

I have custom control, containing a `Popup` which contains a `ListBox`

### Requirement

I need to close the popup and do some logic with the selected item when the user chooses an item. User chooses an item when :

1. he click's on the item with the mouse.
2. he selected and item through keyboard navigation (up/down keys) and clicks enter

### Problem

I have implemented all the above, but my problem is with the events to listen to inorder to execute my logic.

If I execute my logic on the `SelectionChanged` event, It will not fire when the user clicks on the selected item, so I'm missing my first scenario.
If I execute my logic on the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` It will fire before the selection changed so I don't know what the user has chosen. This is also why I can't use both.

I thought of listening on the `ListBoxItem` events to do this ([How to capture a mouse click on an Item in a ListBox in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271375/how-to-capture-a-mouse-click-on-an-item-in-a-listbox-in-wpf)) or firing a command from an implicit `ListBoxItem` style ([WPF Interaction triggers in a Style to invoke commands on View Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759665/wpf-interaction-triggers-in-a-style-to-invoke-commands-on-view-model)) but they didn't work for me.

The best idea that I came up with, is to create some kind of a "post selection" MouseButtonDown event via behaviours or actions, but I am not sure how, or if this is even the way to go.

Any Idea how to create such a thing? Or is there a better solution for this?

Comment: First link you posted suits your need. Can you tell why isn't working by setting event on your listboxItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to `Bind` to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property and to handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event of your control. This way, you'll always know which item is the selected one and when the `Enter` key is hit:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("SelectedItem", typeof(YourDataType), typeof(YourControl), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemPropertyChanged));

public YourDataType SelectedItem 
{
    get { return (YourDataType)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnSelectedItemPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // User has selected an item
}
...
private void Control_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        // User pressed Enter... do something with SelectedItem property here
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, I think I understand your problem a bit better now. The simplest solution would be if you could slightly alter the requirement so that;

1. An item is *selected* with either the mouse or keyboard up/down keys
2. An item is *chosen* with the `Enter` key

That way, you'd always know the selected item when the user chooses. However, if you can't do that, can you handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` instead of the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event? I'm not 100% sure, but I think that that would occur *after* the selection has been made.

Comment: Thanks, but I use `IColletionView` that's binded to my listbox, and I access it's `CurrentItem` property. Should I have another property binded to the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` ? Also how does it solve  the problem where the user clicks on the already selected item?

Comment: I've tried the "auto-select" on mouse over approch before I've posted this question and it does actually work, but I'll use it only as a workaround if I won't find an answer to this. As for you second solution of `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` I haven't tested it (I don't know why it seems so obvious now). I'll test it tomorrow and update accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: Turns out `KeyUp` does occur after selection but for some reason it doesn't fire 100% of the times. I think it's an issue of focus between couple of elements in my `ControlTemplate` but I haven't totally figured it out yet. For now I went ahead with the "auto select on mouse over" approch, So I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Try the `PreviewKeyUp` event. The `KeyUp` event may be handled by one of the relevant controls, whereas you *should* always be able to get the `PreviewKeyUp` event.