# Is it possible to bind to a System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a behavior that I want to track the actions of a control, and I want to read that state off of that behavior from my ViewModel.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
    <MyControl>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <b:MyBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </MyControl>
```

Is there a way I can bind to the behavior as a property of the ViewModel or some other part of the application rather than instantiating it in XAML? What is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is a pure UI concept, the ViewModel is not supposed to know anything about it. However, you could make the behavior update a property of the ViewModel, through a binding. Just declare a dependency property on the behavior and bind it like this:

```
<MyControl>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:MyBehavior MyProperty="{Binding MyViewModelProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</MyControl>
```

(you could also use a `TwoWay` binding if it makes sense of course)

Comment: It's a good idea, but behaviors already inherit from Behavior, and can't inherit from DependencyObject.

Comment: @Dan Monego, [Behavior already inherits from DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.behavior%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)...

Comment: Levensque - oof. Thanks again - I'll just go debug these "A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject" errors over here then.

Comment: What's the `DataContext` that the `Behavior` gets? Why isn't there a `DataContext` property on it? Is there a way to determine the current `DataContext` or internal binding the `Behavior` is currently set to?

Comment: @Shimmy it gets the DataContext of the control

Answer (score 0):

Most of the logic of `Interactivity` is internal or private, for example the attached properties
`Triggers` and `Behaviors` are both private. The `Interaction` class only provides methods to get behaviors and triggers and has no setter methods. I really doubt that there is much that can be done, at least using the existing classes.

Maybe [this question on how to set bahaviors in a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter) can give you an idea how to realize this.