# How can I handle focus changed in a ListView on winrt

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a ListView control in XAML that has items styled by a template.

The template contains a TextBox

When I tab between controls on my keyboard, I get a selection box around the entire template, and on the next tab the focus goes to the first TextBox.

How can I be notified when the focus changes on the ListView?

[update 1]
This is a start:
[How to add a Blend Behavior in a Style Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter)

First I need to hook into the GotFocus/LostFocus events.  The best way to do this is with a behavior, so following the details above, I created a boolean attached property IsScrollIntoViewEnabled.

I then set that value in a style for the ListViewItemContainerStyle.

So phase I is that I know when an item gains and loses focus.  What I still don't know is how to get back from the ListViewItem to the ListView itself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the final piece of the puzzle, getting the ListView from the ListViewItem by walking through VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(x) until I found an object of the correct type.