# Adding a Behavior via a style

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, attachedbehaviors

How would I add a behavior via a style in WPF?

Specifically, I need to add a behavior to a TreeViewItem via the ItemContainerStyle.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="i:Interaction.Behaviors">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <behaviors:MyBehavior/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But at runtime, I get this:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.Setter.Property' threw an exception.' Line number
>   '422' and line position '34'. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: property    at
>   System.Windows.Setter.CheckValidProperty(DependencyProperty property) 
>   at......

There are also errors in the designer:

> The property "Behaviors" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in
>   markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type
>   with an accessible instance property "Behaviors". For attached
>   properties, the declaring type must provide static "GetBehaviors"  and
>   "SetBehaviors" methods.

Comment: Can you show the ItemContainerStyle you have so far?

Comment: @GarryVass I've added what I would *like* to do.

Comment: Are you getting this error at runtime?

Comment: @user3455395 I tell a lie, I think this is Resharper "helping" me. Builds OK.

Comment: Updated with the runtime error

Comment: The designer error is key.  So let's see the declaration of your attached property, including the name spaces...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter

Comment: @user3411327 Yup, good spot. That works perfectly, even though it is a pain to have to go through so much to do something so simple.