# Avoiding conversion errors and associated rendering delay with NullItemSelectorAdapter

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, type-conversion, itemscontrol

In my WPF application I have a DataGrid, and I want the user to be able to filter which rows get displayed. The filtering is implemented like this: on the GUI there is a ComboBox that enumerates the possible values of some property, let's call it `SomeProperty`. When the user selects a value, say `"Value1"`, the DataGrid will only display items with `item.SomeProperty == "Value1"`. Both the DataGrid and the ComboBox contents come from a database.

I want the user to be able to switch off filtering by `SomeProperty`, so I looked for a way to add an `"all"` item to the ComboBox, that returns `null` and that I can use in my filtering logic. I found this:

http://philondotnet.wordpress.com/2009/09/18/how-to-select-null-none-in-a-combobox-listbox-listview

This is a wrapper class that adds a null item to a `ComboBox` or similar. As I am also using `ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath` property, I changed

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NullItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "NullItem", typeof(object), typeof(NullItemSelectorAdapter), new PropertyMetadata("(None)"));
```

to

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NullItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "NullItem", typeof(NullItem), typeof(NullItemSelectorAdapter), new PropertyMetadata(new NullItem()));
```

and added a class like this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(NullItemConverter))]
class NullItem: DynamicObject
{
    private const string Text = "(all)";

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = Text;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        return true;
    }
}

public class NullItemConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return NullItem.Instance;
    }
}
```

in order to be able to use it like this (irrelevant attributes omitted):

```
<view:NullItemSelectorAdapter ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</view:NullItemSelectorAdapter>

<view:NullItemSelectorAdapter ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Description"/>
</view:NullItemSelectorAdapter>
```

etc.

(The objects in the `ItemsSource` are instances of generated classes, so I cannot override their `ToString` method.)

When I call `Application.MainWindow.Show()`, all these ComboBoxes are instantiated, and I get a ton of errors like this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'MyNamespace.View.NullItem' from type 'NullItem' to type 'MyModel.Product' for 'hu-HU' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from MyNamespace.View.NullItem.
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'MyNamespace.View.NullItem' (type 'NullItem'). target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from MyNamespace.View.NullItem.
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

The TypeConverter I've specified does not get instantiated, even though it should be according to the [reference sources of MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/DefaultValueConverter.cs.html).

These errors do not make the program to crash (it runs fine afterwards), but they cause a noticeable delay on when the window contents get rendered, even on fast computers. How can make this delay go away?

I'm mainly interested in a solution that does not involve manually adding a `Converter` to each and every Binding on usages of `NullItemSelectorAdapter`, because that's a lot. I hope that this can be solved by hacking around in the NullItemSelectorAdapter and NullItem classes.

**Solution:**
[Roel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25259672/1813487) below is the solution I went for, because it's a one-liner trick to make the mentioned errors disappear. However [adabyron's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25297141/1813487) is the semantically more correct, more elegant solution and you should use that.

Comment: If you just want to add an empty item to your `ComboBox`es, then you've found a really long way of doing it. Given that typically, items are data bound to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property, you can add an empty item simply using something like: `Items.Add(new YourDataType())`, or perhaps in your case: `Items.Add(new YourDataType("(None)"))`.

Comment: @Sheridan The ComboBoxes are bound to collections not under my control, these come from the database. The ComboBoxes are used to select filtering conditions on a DataGrid, the null item represents no filtering on that specific property whose possible values the ComboBox enumerates.

Comment: I didn't have time to look at your requirements , look in BindingBase.TargetNullValue

Comment: @eranotzap Tried it, but the `TargetNullValue` does not appear in the items.

Comment: The TypeConverter won't work, since it is intended to make an instance of a class usable as a XAML settable attribute value. You can debug it if you set the NullItem property in Xaml on the NullItemSelectorAdapter to a string value, like "(all)". But I still see the conversion error, since it still tries to convert NullItem to Product (or the other types you use)

Comment: @RoelvanWesterop I looked into the [reference sources of `MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/DefaultValueConverter.cs.html) mentioned in the error message, and it's supposed to call `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type)` which should return my TypeConverter. In this case it's probably a bug, or the reference sources are not correct.

Comment: Well, you could create a `DependencyProperty` on the `NullItemSelectorAdapter` which specifies the type you want to add to the `ComboBox` and use `Activator.CreateInstance` and some other reflection magic to set the property you need to have set to the text "(all)"

Comment: @RoelvanWesterop but then, will it return null to the SelectedItem binding source? I'm using that null value in the filtering logic.

Comment: No, it won't return null then. Btw, I only get the error when I bind the SelectedItem of the ComboBox, is that right? If so, how about changing they way you are notified of the change in the selection?

Comment: @RoelvanWesterop I can do that on my own if all else fails. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59249/discussion-between-roel-van-westerop-and-marczellm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second suggestion, after the OP made clear that his client insists on the null-item.
I am sorry to say that I again disregard one of your requirements, which is that SelectedItem is null. But (as stated in a different way in my first answer),

- Having something to add to the ComboBox (the null/all-item)
- yet actually adding `null` (or warping it behind the scenes so it *seems* that way)

just doesn't go together for me.

On the bright side, since the filtering mechanism is definitely under your control, I suppose you should be able to work with the following. If you don't want to add the behavior to every ComboBox, you could use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779168/385995) to apply it in an implicit style.

I've created a ComboBox Behavior that will generically insert the "- All -" item, and added an `IsNullItemSelected` property that you would use instead of `SelectedItem == null` in the filtering. 
Current (known) limitations: I expect the ItemsSource to be an IList and the contained items should either be strings or have a parameterless constructor.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WpfApplication1.Behaviors
{
    public class NullableComboBoxBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
    {
        // IsNullValueSelected 
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsNullValueSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsNullValueSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(NullableComboBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        public bool IsNullValueSelected { get { return (bool)GetValue(IsNullValueSelectedProperty); } set { SetValue(IsNullValueSelectedProperty, value); } }

        private const string AllCaption = "- All -";

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ComboBox))
                    .AddValueChanged(this.AssociatedObject, OnItemsSourceChanged);

            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, typeof(ComboBox))
                    .AddValueChanged(this.AssociatedObject, OnSelectedItemChanged);

            // initial call
            OnItemsSourceChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            OnSelectedItemChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }


        private void OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cbx = this.AssociatedObject;

            // If the caption of the selected item is either "- All -" or no item is selected, 
            // set IsNullValueSelected to true
            if (cbx.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                // get caption directly or by way of DisplayMemberPath
                string caption = cbx.SelectedItem.GetType() == typeof(string) ?
                                    (string)cbx.SelectedItem :
                                    GetDisplayMemberProperty(cbx.SelectedItem).GetValue(cbx.SelectedItem).ToString();

                if (caption == AllCaption || caption == null)
                    this.IsNullValueSelected = true;
                else
                    this.IsNullValueSelected = false;
            }
            else
                this.IsNullValueSelected = true;
        }

        private void OnItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cbx = this.AssociatedObject;

            // assuming an ItemsSource that implements IList
            if (cbx.ItemsSource != null && (IList)cbx.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                Type T = cbx.ItemsSource.AsQueryable().ElementType;

                object obj;

                if (T == typeof(string))
                    obj = AllCaption; // set AllCaption directly
                else if (T.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
                {
                    // set AllCaption by way of DisplayMemberPath
                    obj = Activator.CreateInstance(T);
                    GetDisplayMemberProperty(obj).SetValue(obj, AllCaption);
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Only types with parameterless ctors or string are supported.");

                // insert the null item
                ((IList)cbx.ItemsSource).Insert(0, obj);

                // select first item (optional). 
                // If you uncomment this, remove the OnSelectedItemChanged call in OnAttached 
                //cbx.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private PropertyInfo GetDisplayMemberProperty(object obj)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.AssociatedObject.DisplayMemberPath))
                throw new Exception("This will only work if DisplayMemberPath is set.");

            // get the property info of the DisplayMemberPath
            return obj.GetType().GetProperty(this.AssociatedObject.DisplayMemberPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"
            xmlns:beh="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Behaviors"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="580">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ComboBoxResetViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,2" Width="150" >
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <beh:NullableComboBoxBehavior IsNullValueSelected="{Binding IsNullValueSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Text="SelectedItem:" FontWeight="SemiBold"  Margin="50,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, FallbackValue='null'}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="IsNullValueSelected:" FontWeight="SemiBold"  Margin="30,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsNullValueSelected}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class ComboBoxResetViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get { return _items; } set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); } }

        private ItemViewModel _selectedItem;
        public ItemViewModel SelectedItem { get { return _selectedItem; } set { _selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); } }

        private bool _isNullValueSelected;
        public bool IsNullValueSelected { get { return _isNullValueSelected; } set { _isNullValueSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsNullValueSelected"); } }

        public ComboBoxResetViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>()
                {
                    new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 1" },
                    new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 2" },
                    new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 3" },
                    new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 4" },
                    new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 5" }
                };
        }
    }

    public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now what should I do? Roel solved my problem with a one-liner and I promised him the bounty in chat, yet both of your solutions show great effort and are more elegant. IMO the "semantically correct" solution would be to accept his answer (because I used his solution after all) and give you the bounty. Do you care about the reputation?

Comment: @marczellm accept this answer and give him the bounty. This is the most elegant solution without disregarding your requirements.

Comment: No, I don't care about the reputation. Do whatever you feel is right. I would like to get the accepted answer more than the bounty, because this influences people more for what they will use, and I obviously think that my suggestions are more appealing than the NullItemSelectorAdapter and Converters, but you decide and I will not gripe.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to inherit the NullItem class from MyModel.Product, the conversion will succeed. Or, if inheritance is not possible, wrap the objects and bind to them.

Edit after discussion:
If you change the type of the property you bind the selecteditem to to object, the errors will disappear.

Comment: Cannot inherit, because there are different types involved in different ComboBoxes.

Comment: Now what should I do? You solved my problem with a one-liner and I promised you the bounty in chat, but adabyron's solutions show great effort and are quite elegant, too. IMO the "semantically correct" solution would be to accept your answer (because I used your solution after all) and give him the bounty. Do you care about the reputation?

Answer (score 1):

While I can understand the null item approach, because it's been used many times, I find it much more clean to make a difference between

- Selecting an item
- Removing your selection

thus not "selecting nothing by selecting something", especially if the requirement is for the SelectedItem to be null.

I would suggest creating a custom control, extending the combobox with a reset button:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The custom control:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1.Controls
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ResetButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
    public class ComboBoxReset : ComboBox
    {
        private Button _resetButton;

        // reset event (not used in this demo case, but should be provided)
        public static readonly RoutedEvent ResetEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Reset", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ComboBoxReset));
        public event RoutedEventHandler Reset { add { AddHandler(ResetEvent, value); } remove { RemoveHandler(ResetEvent, value); } }
        private void OnReset()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(ResetEvent);
            RaiseEvent(args);
        }

        public ComboBoxReset()
        {
            // lookless control, get default style from generic.xaml
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ComboBoxReset), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ComboBoxReset)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            if (this.Template != null)
            {
                // find reset button in template
                Button btn = this.Template.FindName("PART_ResetButton", this) as Button;
                if (_resetButton != btn)
                {
                    // detach old handler
                    if (_resetButton != null)
                        _resetButton.Click -= ResetButton_Click;

                    _resetButton = btn;

                    // attach new handler
                    if (_resetButton != null)
                        _resetButton.Click += ResetButton_Click;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // reset the selected item and raise the event
            this.SelectedItem = null;
            OnReset();
        }
    }
}
```

For the style, basically just get the default template of a normal ComboBox through VS designer, add the button (look for `PART_ResetButton` in the code below), change the TargetType (to `ComboBoxReset`), put it in Themes\generic.xaml. Not much to it. Here's how the style looked for me:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="4,4,21,4" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
<Geometry x:Key="DownArrowGeometry">M 0 0 L 3.5 4 L 7 0 Z</Geometry>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#AFAFAF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RoundCorners="false" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#AFAFAF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="Placement" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Placement}">
                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
        <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="RenderFocused" TargetName="Border" Value="true"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:ComboBoxReset}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:ComboBoxReset}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                        <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                    </Popup>
                    <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="PART_ResetButton" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,0,0,0" >
                        <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/remove.png" />
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The implementation (producing the screenshots above):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Controls"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ComboBoxResetViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <ctrl:ComboBoxReset ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,2" Width="150" />
        <TextBlock Text="SelectedItem:" FontWeight="SemiBold"  Margin="50,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, FallbackValue='null'}" Margin="5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And finally the viewmodel I used for testing:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class ComboBoxResetViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private List<ItemViewModel> _items;
        public List<ItemViewModel> Items { get { return _items; } set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); } }

        private ItemViewModel _selectedItem;
        public ItemViewModel SelectedItem { get { return _selectedItem; } set { _selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); } }

        public ComboBoxResetViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new List<ItemViewModel>()
            {
                new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 1" },
                new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 2" },
                new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 3" },
                new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 4" },
                new ItemViewModel() { Name = "Item 5" }
            };
        }
    }

    public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll take a look at your solution. In my case there used to be a checkbox next to the combobox, and by checking that, you could turn off filtering by that value. But the client requested that I turn it into an "(all)" item in the ComboBox.