# Do not load image source until stack panel is seen

Tags: c#, wpf

My program requires loading a large set of images within one scrollable view (around 1K)
My code:

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"> <!-- Stack panel of stack panels -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <local:Widget Text="1" Image="https://exaple.com/" /> <!-- local class purpose of is placing image and text in one line -->
            <local:Widget Text="1" Image="https://exaple.com/" />
            <local:Widget Text="1" Image="https://exaple.com/" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <local:Widget Text="1" Image="https://exaple.com/" />
            <local:Widget Text="1" Image="https://exaple.com/" />
            <local:Widget Text="1" Image="https://exaple.com/" />
        </StackPanel>
        ...
    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Problem is that before launching wpf goes to every website and downloads all images at once, how can I say wpf to download and show them on user seeing them?

---- EDIT

I have pinpointed the issue with scrollviewer demanding everything all at once, either I use `CanContentScroll` or not, I also tried using `ListBox` with `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"`, but it also did not work, still looking for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about 7 hours of pure hell I did it (I mean I did find it)
[Loading a large amount of images to be displayed in a WrapPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641606/loading-a-large-amount-of-images-to-be-displayed-in-a-wrappanel)
Without cache and other not so important for me classes I found a ScrollViewer implementation that checks every on every scroll changed if any `StackPanel`'s are in the view and with `DataTrigger` it changes to whatever you want it to, and as much as I like this answer the more I hate how things works) Hope I'll help anyone