# Retrieve GroupName in Listview Grouping in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

I've setup a ListView with grouping and I would like to retrieve the GroupName when I right click on the group in MVVM. I've placed a `ContextMenu` on my group style, and I was trying to use the EventToCommand from System.Windows.Interactivity to get the underlying item.

Here the relevant part:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Expander IsExpanded="False" Template="{StaticResource CustomizedExpander}" Background="#FFEBEBEB" BorderThickness="0" ContextMenu="{StaticResource GroupContextMenu}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=OnCategorySelected}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <!--N.B. The "Name" property is part of the CollectionViewSource-->
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF767676" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" Foreground="#FF454545" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" Foreground="#FF767676" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

I don't know if it's the right way to do it but it seems the command is not triggered at all.

Any suggestion?

UPDATE:

The whole thing was much simpler than I thought. The interaction part was not required at all. Fixing the binding is enough to get the underlying category when the context menu is shown:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Modifications}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Execute" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OnExecuteScript, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" Visibility="{Binding CanExecute, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Execute up to this" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OnExecuteScriptUpToThis, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" Visibility="{Binding CanOnlyBeExecutedSequentially, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Drop" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OnExecuteDrop, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Visibility="{Binding Drop, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
            <MenuItem Header="Dump" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OnExecuteDump, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Visibility="{Binding CanDump, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
        </ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="GroupContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Dump all" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OnExecuteDumpAll, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Object Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="50">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Deploy}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Object Name" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ObjectName}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListViewItem}" >
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Drop}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource GroupContextMenu}" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander IsExpanded="False" Template="{StaticResource CustomizedExpander}" Background="#FFEBEBEB" BorderThickness="0">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <!--N.B. The "Name" property is part of the CollectionViewSource-->
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF767676" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" Foreground="#FF454545" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" Foreground="#FF767676" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: As far as i know its not possible to use Blend behaviors in Styles. But maybe you can use this workaround: 
[How to add a Blend Behavior in a Style Setter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter)

Comment: I've tried the solution in your link but it doesn't seems to work.. Do you know any alternative way to try to access the selected group?

Comment: Maybe you could try to `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` as Event. You bound a `ContextMenu` and a `MouseRightButtonDown` event. If ContextMenu is called first and sets `e.Handled` the other events are never called. Maybe this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i think i've figured out why your Command isnt firing.

Since you are in an Template, the DataContext has Changed. Therefore your CommandBinding should look like this:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.OnCategorySelected}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Also, your CommandParameter should not be `Name` because you'll only get a string in the end instead the whole Object.

If you use my above code you will get the whole `CollectionViewGroup` instead. In said `CollectionViewGroup` you'll find all the Items in the group. If you are fine with getting just the Groupname you can proceed with you implementation of course.

I dont really understand why you are using a `ContextMenu` and what it does (Since you dont posted that code), but if you are interested in how you can display the grouped Items in such a ContextMenu, you can do it like this:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="False"  Background="#FFEBEBEB" BorderThickness="0" >
          <Expander.ContextMenu>
                   <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
          </Expander.ContextMenu>
</Expander>
```

Since we now know, what we have to deal with (It's still an `CollectionViewGroup`) we can set the Items of it as ItemsSource of the ContextMenu.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works like a charm!! The issue was in the binding. I have a minor issue, when the category is created during the ListView binding, the command is invoked even if I don't right click the category. Do you have any suggestion about it?

Comment: Just a note on your answer: the Name is of type object and it reflects the same type used in group creation (in my case an enum type)

Comment: Solved! The issue was in the CommandParameter="{Binding}. Binding just the "Name" made the issue disappear! I'm trying to award you the bounty but SO says I've to wait 5 hours...