# How to add the Behaviors in Style

Tags: c#, wpf

When i added the style for Interaction.Behaviors in XAML, it have been error as below. Actually, i just want to add the common style and it will be using in each view.

So, should i add the more?

> The property "Behaviors" does not have an accessible setter.
>
> The property "Behaviors" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type with an accessible instance property "Behaviors". For attached properties, the declaring type must provide static "GetBehaviors"  and "SetBehaviors" methods.

i have error in this line.

```
<Setter Property="e:Interaction.Behaviors">
    <Setter.Value>
```

here is my all sample source code.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ToolTipTouchStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <!--<Setter Property="e:Interaction.Behaviors" Value="localToolTip:ToolTipTouchScreen" />-->
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="e:Interaction.Behaviors">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <localToolTip:ToolTipTouchScreen />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

public class ToolTipTouchScreen : Behavior<UIElement>
{

    Timer timer { get; set; }
    ToolTip toolTip { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;

        AssociatedObject.MouseLeave += OnMouseLeave;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnMouseLeftButtonUp;

    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.MouseLeave -= OnMouseLeave;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp -= OnMouseLeftButtonUp;
    }

    public void OnMouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseToolTip();
    }

    public void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((dynamic)sender).ToolTip is string)
        {
            toolTip = new ToolTip();
            toolTip.Content = ((dynamic)sender).ToolTip;

        }
        else
        {
            toolTip = (ToolTip)((dynamic)sender).ToolTip;
        }
        
        
        toolTip.IsOpen = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void CloseToolTip()
    {
        if (toolTip != null)
        {
            toolTip.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)CloseToolTip, DispatcherPriority.Send);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a Blend Behavior in a Style Setter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting it within the control definition, as in.

```
   xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.Behavior;assembly=MyNameSpace"            

<ControlType Text="Something">
<ControlType.Behaviors>
<behaviors:EmailValidatorBehavior />
</ControlType.Behaviors>
</ControlType>
```