# Use behavior in style

Tags: c#, wpf, attachedbehaviors

I have a behavior ,How can I use it in TextBlock Style so that it gets applied to all TextBlocks.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Distance}" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:EmptyToNaBehaviour/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

this is my attached behavior which is basically changing the empty value to N/A

```
 public class EmptyToNaBehaviour : Behavior<TextBlock>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var txtblock = this.AssociatedObject as TextBlock;

        if (txtblock != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtblock.Text))
        {
            txtblock.Text = "N/A";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically two different ways of implementing behaviours in WPF, commonly referred to as attached behaviours and Blend behaviours.

An attached behaviour is simply an attached property with a `PropertyChangedCallback` change handler attached to it that performs some action on or extends the `DependencyObject` to which it is attached when the value of the dependency property changes.

You typically define an attached behaviour as a static class with a set of static methods that get and set the value of the dependency property and perform the desired logic as a result of the callback being invoked. You could easily set the value of any such properties in a Style:

```
<Setter Property="local:EmptyToNaBehaviour.SomeProperty" Value="x"/>
```

A Blend behaviour provides a better way of encapsulating the functionality of a behaviour compared to an ordinary attached behaviour. They are also more design friendly easily as they can be easily attached to visual elements in the UI via drag-drop functionality in Blend. But I am afraid you cannot really add a Blend behaviour to a `Style` setter:

[How to add a Blend Behavior in a Style Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter)

So if you want to be able to apply your behaviour in the context of a `Style`, you should write an attached behaviour instead of a Blend behaviour.

**Edit:** Your behaviour is a Blend behaviour. Replace it by an attached behaviour:

```
public class EmptyToNaBehaviour
{
    public static string GetText(TextBlock textBlock)
    {
        return (string)textBlock.GetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetText(TextBlock textBlock, string value)
    {
        textBlock.SetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(EmptyToNaBehaviour),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnTextChanged));

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock txtblock = d as TextBlock;
        if(txtblock != null)
            txtblock.Loaded += Txtblock_Loaded;
    }

    private static void Txtblock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock txtblock = sender as TextBlock;
        string text = GetText(txtblock);
        if (txtblock != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtblock.Text))
        {
            txtblock.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1" Text="text"
           Behaviors:EmptyToNaBehaviour.Text="N/A">
</TextBlock>
```

**Or in a Style:**

```
<Style x:Key="style" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Behaviors:EmptyToNaBehaviour.Text" Value="N/A" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I have added my attached behavior to question which doesn't have a dependency property,could you suggest solution to set in style in this case.

Comment: That's a Blend behaviour and as mentioned you cannot apply such a behaviour to a Style.

Comment: But why are you even using a behaviour here? You could easily accomplish the same functionality in the Style itself.

Comment: yeah I tried that,but I am not able to use trigger and setter on same property "Text".