# How can I set a behavior for each ListViewItem generated by the parent ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listviewitem, attachedbehaviors

I have defined the following behavior for `ListBoxItem`s :

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace MyBehavior {
    public partial class ListBoxSelectableBehavior : Behavior<ListBoxItem> {
        protected override void OnAttached( ) => base.OnAttached( );
    }
}
```

( Obviously there is more to it than this, but because [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and that's not relevant to my question, I'm just presenting the relevant portion. Also, since `ListViewItem` inherits `ListBoxItem` directly, it's valid for either case. )

I need to know how I can take the above defined behavior and attach it to `ListViewItem`s generated by the following :

```
<Window
    x:Class="MCVE.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MCVE"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="ListViewSource" Type="{x:Type lib:String}">
            <lib:String>Foo</lib:String>
            <lib:String>Bar</lib:String>
            <lib:String>Baz</lib:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource ListViewSource}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

I know that to attach behaviors to elements, you need to import the `System.Windows.Interactivity` namespace, and define it in XAML, and the XAML would be...

```
<myFoo:Bar>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <!-- Behaviors Go Here -->
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</myFoo:Bar>
```

What I don't know is where I would put that to have it affect the `ListView` generated items.

So... how do I get my defined behavior to affect my `ListView` generated items?

Comment: ListView.ItemContainerStyle

Comment: @DaveM So... what? I just plop the XAML directly in the style?

Comment: Either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/ or implement your behavior as an AttachedProperty instead (one reason I prefer to implement “behaviors” as AttachedProperties)